# Word meaning 'easily pleased?'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Especially when used pejoratively. Used to described someone who is easily pleased by small things that are very common or that people can get easily.

Comment: when you say 'pleased', do you mean, accepting of/satisfied by' or 'delighted by'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it meets the criteria established by [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a writing-help and word-game and crossword-puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be *undiscerning*, which if taken in a perjorative sense can mean someone who is lacking in taste.

Answer (score 2):

possibly [**complaisant**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/complaisant) - If you are complaisant, you are willing to accept what other people are doing without complaining.

> Example: Because John is too **complaisant** in his willingness to please others, people often take advantage of him.
>
> Example: Hector was a poor manager because he was too **complaisant**, being pleased with his staff working, but not considering the quality of what they did.

[collinsdictionary.com]

Comment: _"complaisant in his willingness to please others"_ Is that not a tautology? Also, isn't there a difference between "willing to please others" (complaisant) and "easily pleased" (which refers to _the person himself_ being pleased)?

Comment: @Flater - possibly not a good example, but the full meaning of the example is that John, in his willingness to accept what others are doing, pleases them by allowing them to take advantage of him. I could probably have found a better example - I'll have a look.

Comment: @LeeLeon As your further comment shows, this word is much more about being disposed to please others than being actively pleased with anything oneself, so I'm not sure its a good fit. Can you come up with usages which speak more to the degree of 'pleasedness' of the complaisant person?

Comment: An interesting word. It is rare and I wonder if that is because in speech it will be confused with 'complacent'.

Answer (score 1):

I think **[uncritical](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uncritical)** will fit well here.

> *accepting something too easily, because of being unwilling or unable to criticize.*
>
> Example: An adoring, uncritical audience

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the title question is **undemanding**.

From [M-W Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/undemanding):

> *undemanding*  adjective ...  not demanding:...
>
> b of a person : not expecting much time, attention, effort, etc., from
>   other
>   people : not difficult to satisfy
>
> *He is an enjoyable, undemanding guest.*

Answer (score -1):

I have three options that come to mind.

[**Excitable**](https://www.google.com/search?q=exciteable&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS756US756&oq=exciteable&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l3.3199j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), adj.

> *responding rather too readily to something new or stimulating; too easily excited.*
>
> Chip could be a bit wayward and excitable

[**Good-natured**](https://www.google.com/search?q=good+natured&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS756US756&oq=good+natured&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1863j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), adj.

> *kind, friendly, and patient.*
>
> Everyone was very good-natured about my comments.

[**Affable**](https://www.google.com/search?q=affable&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS756US756&oq=affable&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i60j0.1608j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), adj.

> *friendly, good-natured, or easy to talk to.*
>
> He was an affable and agreeable companion.

Comment: Explain the downvote?